# jQuery plugin, shake ..

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback, position

i have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym4NP/2/ why the 'content' div does not move to up , move only to down ? and how i send `$this` ( selector ) to callback function ?

Comment: What exactly should this JSFiddle do?

Comment: It moves back 'up' (to the middle of it's containers) for me in FF 8. What browser are you using? Also, it's a bit of an annoying effect, unless you've exaggerated it for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @JamWaffles, i using Chrome 16..

Comment: positions really should be an array not an object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use jQuery UI to do this effect.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kEKtw/2/

With this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').effect("shake", {direction:'up', times:10}, 0);
});
```

Notes:

- I changed the css to make the numbers add up or the UI code would have issues.
- If you look at how jQUI implements shake you will see the "effects" stack is implemented as an array as I suggest below.

---

The reason positions should be an array:

What you really want to do is set up a sequence like this:

- move up random amount
- wait set time
- move back to center
- wait set time
- move down random amount

However using positions as an object does not give ordering nor does it allow you to repeat commands (since ever command is an object property name which must be unique.)

If it was an array you could set up something like this to pass into the plugin:

```
 positions: [
        'U': -300,
        'W' : 1000,
        'C' : 0,
        'W' : 1000,
        'D': 300
    ],
```

---

**Old answer**

The code is complex, but your problem is simple.

At each "move" in the shake you change the relative location of the top or bottom to a new number from 1 to 300.  This means the item will move between 1 and 300+object size.  I believe what you want to do is move it between -300 and +300.  To do this you will need to change the `U` command to set a value of -300 to 0 not 0 to 300

There is another error in the logic -- it does not reset the box to the center.

Comment: I trying adding '-' .. `case 'D': $object.css ( 'top' , $rand ( $r ) + 'px' ) ; break;
                                                         case 'U': $object.css ( 'top' , '-' + $rand ( $r ) + 'px' ) ; break;` and not works.

Comment: How can i fix this reset problem ?